# jQuery selectors - change attribute of a tag when clicking on another tag located under a common parent tag

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following html structure:

```
<div>
<button>
<img src="img/a.png" />
</button>
<h2>Title</h2>
</div>
```

The behaviour I would like to achieve is that, when the user clicks on the h2 title, the image in the button field changes. I have tried the following jQuery code, but it won't work and I'd be glad if someone could help me pointing out where I went wrong:

```
$('h2').click(function(){
    $(this).parentsUntil('div').children('button').children('img').attr('src','img/b.png');
});
```

Thanks very much in advance

Comment: `parentsUntil()` will get all parents *until* the `'div'`.  So, before the `'div'`, there are zero parents.  You just want `parent()` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('h2').click(function(){
    $(this).siblings('button').children('img').attr('src','img/b.png');
});
```

And of course the customary fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/UbMyW/

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead a little bit more simple

```
$('h2').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().find('img').attr('src','img/b.png');
});
```

See example here http://jsfiddle.net/kXjPY/1/